# Как работает [[Scope]] у вложенных друг в друга функций

Tags: javascript, теория

Есть такой код:

```
function outer(){
    a = 'Привет';
  inner();
}

function inner(){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Очевидно что `console.log(a)` выведет `'Привет'`.

Однако если продумать то `inner()` и `outer()` ищут переменные в `LexicalEnvironment` окна, а в нем нет переменной `a`, но 'inner()' берет ее из собственного `LexicalEnvironment`, то откуда `a` берет `outer()`?

Comment: Вы не объявили переменную "а" и она "улетела" в глобальный Scope. Там её и нашёл inner. Если написать `var a = 'Привет'`, то вы получите undefined в console.log

Comment: Добавте в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не объявили переменную "а" и она "улетела" в глобальный Scope. Там её и нашёл inner. Если написать `var a = 'Привет'`, то вы получите undefined в console.log